# Usage of defined(in_index)

Tags: php

I found this line of code in one of my file taken from someone else, it has this line to restrict users from accessing the file, can someone explain this line of code because I need to restrict access to my system files

```
if(!defined('IN_INDEX')) { die('Sorry, you cannot access this file.'); }
```

Comment: Well it checks if IN_INDEX has been defined using define function somewhere in the code earlier, define function is used to set some constant values globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common trick to prevent direct access to a PHP file. For example, with this file structure:

```
|- index.php
|- db.php
```

Assuming `db.php` contains database connection information and initialization, you don't want the user to access this file directly (even if he can't read source code). You only use `db.php` by including it from another script.

So, in `db.php`, you write the line:

```
if(!defined('IN_INDEX')) { die('Sorry, you cannot access this file.'); }
```

And, in `index.php`, before including `db.php` you *define* `IN_INDEX`, like this:

```
define('IN_INDEX', true);
include 'db.php';
```

Then `db.php` will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

That just checks to see if IN_INDEX has been defined previously. It would have been defined as part of an authentication function in another part of the script.